# Android Studio show black (blank) screen during setup

Tags: android-studio, installation

I have used Android Studio for a few years on my old Mac Mini for developing apps with Cordova. But to keep up with the latest iOS and Android versions I had to replace my Mac Mini with newer hardware and software. So I am running a brand new Mac Mini with M2 processor and 24GB RAM. It's running Macos Ventura 13.0.
So I downloaded the latest Android Studio Electric Eel and run the setup. But the setup wizard shows just a blank (black) screen. Also opening the About and Preferences windows from the menu show nothing but a blank screen.

I installed the Mac Arm version, and I also tried the Intel version but that gives the same result. I searched on Google for a solution but I can only find blank screen issues for the Android Emulator ... but I don't get that far.

I could try to install older versions but I prefer to install the latest versions to keep up with current versions of Android and iOS.

Does anybody run into this issue as well and is there a known solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a conflict between Android Studio and PhpStorm (which uses the same IDE platform). PhpStorm was running in the background and when I got it to the foreground that screen was also black. I closed PhpStorm and it worked normally again. So I started Android Studio the setup also showed a normal window.
For now I consider this issue solved :-)